# Build a graph based on the values ​from the database between two time periods

Tags: php, sql-server, canvas, input

im trying to build a graph based on values from Ms SQL Database. Here what i thought, but is show only one point :

```
<?php

//----------------------Connect with Server--------------------------
$serverName = "DESKTOP-MLENLVF"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DataBaseExample", "UID"=>"g.abibekov", "PWD"=>"dprb-725");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
//----------------------End Connecting with Server--------------------------


if(isset($_POST["FirstDateButton"]))
{
    $firstdatetime=htmlspecialchars($_POST['FirstDate']);
    $seconddatetime=htmlspecialchars($_POST['SecondDate']);
    $query=sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ValueTime WHERE Date between cast('$firstdatetime' as Date) 
    and cast('$seconddatetime' as Date)"); 
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
    {        
       $dataPoints = array(array("y" => $row['Value'], "label" => $row['Date']));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `sqlsrv_num_rows($query)` please check,

Answer (score 2):

By using only `$dataPoints = array(array("y" => $row['Value'], "label" => $row['Date']));` you are overriding all the data in the `$dataPoint` and storing only the last value from the `while` loop.

In order to fix this, you could do it like this:

```
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{
  $dataPoints[] = array(array("y" => $row['Value'], "label" => $row['Date']));
}
```

Or like this:

```
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{        
   $tmp = array(array("y" => $row['Value'], "label" => $row['Date']));
   array_push($dataPoints, $tmp);
}
```